# LEFT OUTER JOIN returns no rows

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-erp

I have two tables with the same key. I want to, in one SELECT, **without subsequent manipulation of data in an internal table**, retrieve all records in the left-hand table where there is NO CORRESPONDING record in the right-hand table (i.e. columns from the right-hand table would be empty).

The most logical thing to do would be the following, but this does not compile, because you may not use a field from the right-hand side in an outer join in the WHERE clause:

```
  select e~equnr into lt_equnr
    from equi as e
    left outer join eqbs as b on e~equnr = b~equnr
    where e~matnr = material
      and b~b_werk = space.
```

An alternative that looks promising and compiles is this, but it does not work, as it brings back even those that have corresponding entries in the right-hand table:

```
  select e~equnr into table lt_equnr
    from equi as e
    left outer join eqbs as b on e~equnr = b~equnr
    and b~b_werk = space
      where e~matnr = material.
```

This option merely blanks out fields from the right-hand side, but still includes everything in the result set. This can be confirmed by selecting fields from the right-hand side.

Another option, which also does not work, is using a sub-select:

```
  select e~equnr into table lt_equnr
    from equi as e
    where e~matnr = material
      and e~equnr not in ( select equnr from equi where equnr = e~equnr ).
```

Comment: Could You try to add the material condition into Your subselect, if the field consist there ) ???

Comment: No, it is not a field in the right-hand table.

Comment: You seem to have a mistake in your sub-select, this should be a select from eqbs.

Comment: Ah, man, how did I miss that? Thanks for pointing that out! When I am at work tomorrow I will see if that resolves the problem! (It always helps to have an extra pair of eyes on your code! :-)

Comment: As @GertBeukema pointed out, there is a bug in my code. The sub-select would actually have worked. Thanks for that.

Comment: As indicated in my final answer, this was a typo. They now have a off-topic close category for that. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments on the question, there was a bug in my code. In my sub-select I was using the LHS table. (My sub-select was referencing EQUI instead of EQBS).

By fixing my sub-select thus, it works:

```
  select e~equnr into table lt_equnr
    up to max_entries rows
    from equi as e
    where e~matnr = material
      and e~equnr not in ( select equnr from eqbs where equnr = e~equnr ).
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is not a good practice. You put the burden of the calculation on the database server, of which you have only one, instead of the application server, of which you can have practically unlimited number.

Comment: I know you said you do not want to manipulate internal tables, but you should not want this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with a subquery:

```
SELECT e~equnr INTO TABLE lt_equnr
  FROM equi AS e
  WHERE e~matnr = material
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b~equnr
                       FROM eqbs as b
                       WHERE b~equnr = e~equnr ).
```

Comment: As you see from my question, I did try a subquery, but as pointed out in the comments, I was using the primary table in the subquery, so probably a bug on my side!